# Best way to execute function once computed property updates

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Currently I have a component that has a computed property that updates from the Vuex store.  This part works perfectly.  What I'm confused about is once that computed property updates, I have to always tweak the data accordingly for my view.  WHat is the best way to achieve this?

For example:

My component has:

```
    computed: {
        players: function() {
            return this.$store.state.players;
        },
```

I previously had a function `setupPlayers(data)` that tweaked this info and provided it for the view.

My question now is if computed players changes I'd like to run a function that tweaks the data for the view.  How do I do this?  OR is my approach incorrect?

Comment: Since you are using a computed property, once you update the state it should automatically update the view, do you see a different behavior?

Comment: The primary use case of a computed is calculating derived data ("tweaking" it). Why not just do it in the computed you already have?

Answer (score 7):

You should make data you are updating a computed property and have it dependant on the `players` computed property:

```
computed: {
  players: function() {
    return this.$store.state.players;
  },
  myData: function() { // will update automatically whenever this.players changes
    var players = this.players;
    // do something players data
  }
}
```

If you're unable to make that data a computed property for any reason, then you could also just use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers):

```
watch: {
  players: function(value) {
    // update your data
  }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, it is a computed property

Comment: You can watch computed properties. OP is asking how to update separate data whenever a computed property updates.

Comment: computed acts exactly like a watcher so whats the point of watching it?

Comment: Yeah, in this case, I think making another computed based on the first would be better than using a watcher. But in general, I don't put code in a computed property's function that doesn't affect the returned value. So, for example, if OP needed to make an api call whenever his computed property changed, I'd say it makes much more sense to put that in a watcher than in the computed property's definition. It would work either way, but it's easier to grok IMO.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 approaches here:

1. Don't access the data directly from the state, but rather via a [getter](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html), and then the getter can manipulate the data before returning it.
2. You can run any logic in the computed property before returning it, as long as you are not performing async or heavy operations, so you can just manipulate the players array in the computed:

   ```
   computed: {
       players: function() {
           var players = this.$store.state.players;
           //do something here
           ....
           return players;
       },
   ```

Comment: Make sure you are not modifying the `players` array, otherwise you need to deep clone it first. Or commit a mutation if you really want to change the store value.